# Get list of Facebook pages which are followed by the user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I do it with http api? The final goal is to list all events of pages user is subscribed to. I couldn't find this in docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"All the Pages this person has liked": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/

Page Events: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events

It is not possible to get a list of Pages you "follow": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/subscribedto

> This endpoint was removed as of version 2.0 of the Graph API.

Comment: Like and Follow are a different things

Comment: you asked about pages - you cannot get user profiles the user follows. pages and user profiles are different things ;)

Comment: pages which are *followed*, not *liked*

Comment: I don't need list of followed user profiles, only list of followed pages. To follow a page you don't need to *like* it, there is a separate *follow* button.